# Keep tab open after opening file - keyboard shortcut.

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can open a file with ctrl + p with VSCode, and that's good.

But I want to make the tab stay there (be non-italicised), using a keyboard shortcut. (The only way I know how to do this is to either modify the file, or to double click the tab).

What is the command palette name for this action, and is there a default keyboard shortcut for it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The command palette name for this action is `View: Keep Editor`. The default keybinding for this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> (on macOS, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>). The command name for keybindings.json is `workbench.action.keepEditor`.

Comment: That's a great tip, didn't know there is a shortcut for that. But do you maybe know if there is a way to keep files open by default when opening them through quick access (Ctrl + P)?

Comment: Or "⌘+K Enter" on mac!

Comment: @dzenesiz set "workbench.editor.enablePreview" to false.
See: https://medium.com/statuscode/jumping-to-files-in-visual-studio-code-and-keeping-them-open-45d7b9d2f5

Comment: @CaptainSquirrel Taht worked prefectly. Thanks! Why don't you make it an asnwer?